# List of concurrency models

Tags: concurrency

I'd like a large list so I can reference this for ideas. Some answers already have been enlightening .

What are some concurrency models? I heard of message passing where there is no memory shared. Futures which returns an object right away (so it doesn't block) and allows you to dereference the original function returns value later when you need it blocking if the results are not ready yet. I heard of coroutines, software transactional memory and random others.

I searched for a list or a wiki and couldn't find any good ones (many did not list the 3 I mentioned above) and many results gave me a complicated description explaining how it works rather then what it does or how it is to be used.

What are some concurrency models and what is a simple description of what they do? One per answer.

Comment: [Concurrency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_%28computer_science%29) from Wikipedia is a good start. It lists (and links) a number of models not yet mentioned.

Comment: Also note this thread currently has answers the wiki page makes no mention of. Lets have more

Comment: check out this for a comparision of the major ones: http://java-is-the-new-c.blogspot.de/2014/01/comparision-of-different-concurrency.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## COM Threading (Concurrency) Model

- Single-Threaded Apartments
- Multi-Threaded Apartments
- Mixed Model Development

> COM objects can be used in multiple threads of a process. The terms
>   "**Single- threaded Apartmen**t" (STA) and
>   "**Multi-threaded Apartment**" (MTA) are
>   used to create a conceptual framework
>   for describing the relationship
>   between objects and threads, the
>   concurrency relationships among
>   objects, the means by which method
>   calls are delivered to an object, and
>   the rules for passing interface
>   pointers among threads. Components and
>   their clients choose between the
>   following two apartment models
>   presently supported by COM:
>
> Single-threaded Apartment model (STA):
>   One or more threads in a process use
>   COM and calls to COM objects are
>   synchronized by COM. Interfaces are
>   marshaled between threads. A
>   degenerate case of the single-threaded
>   apartment model, where only one thread
>   in a given process uses COM, is called
>   the single-threading model. Previous
>   Microsoft information and
>   documentation has sometimes referred
>   to the STA model simply as the
>   "apartment model." Multi-threaded
>   Apartment model (MTA): One or more
>   threads use COM and calls to COM
>   objects associated with the MTA are
>   made directly by all threads
>   associated with the MTA without any
>   interposition of system code between
>   caller and object. Because multiple
>   simultaneous clients may be calling
>   objects more or less simultaneously
>   (simultaneously on multi-processor
>   systems), objects must synchronize
>   their internal state by themselves.
>   Interfaces are not marshaled between
>   threads. Previous Microsoft
>   information and documentation has
>   sometimes referred to this model as
>   the "free-threaded model." Both the
>   STA model and the MTA model can be
>   used in the same process. This is
>   sometimes referred to as a
>   "mixed-model" process.

---

## Other models according to Wikipedia

> There are several models of concurrent
>   computing, which can be used to
>   understand and analyze concurrent
>   systems. These models include:
>
> - [Actor model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model)
>
>   - [Object-capability mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-capability_model)l for security
> - [Petri nets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petri_net)
> - [Process calculi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_calculus) such as
>
>   - [Ambient calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambient_calculus)
>   - [Calculus of Communicating Systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calculus_of_Communicating_Systems) (CCS)
>   - [Communicating Sequential Processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_Sequential_Processes) (CSP)
>   - [π-calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi_calculus)

Comment: +1 for Petri nets!  I hadn't heard of them, but they are a nice analogy for Scala's for-comprehensions and maybe Pythons sequence comprehensions too.

Answer (score 11):

## [Actor Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model)

> I heard of message passing where there is no memory shared.

Is it about Erlang-style Actors?

Scala uses this idea in its Actors framework (thus, in Scala its not a part of the language, just a library) and it looks quite sexy!

In a few words Actors are objects that have no shared data at all, but can use async messages for interaction. Actors can be located on one or different hosts and use interesting error handling policy (when error happened - actor just dies).

You should read more on this in Erlang and Scala docs, its really straightforward and progressive approach!

Chapters 3, 17, 17.11:

http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaByExample.pdf
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model

Comment: Thanks, Cedrik, exactly. Had not enough reputation to post the second link :D

Answer (score 7):

## [Futures](http://www.ps.uni-saarland.de/alice/manual/futures.html)

> A future is a place-holder for the
> undetermined result of a (concurrent)
> computation. Once the computation
> delivers a result, the associated
> future is eliminated by globally
> replacing it with the result value.
> That value may be a future on its own.
>
> Whenever a future is requested by a
> concurrent computation, i.e. it tries
> to access its value, that computation
> automatically synchronizes on the
> future by blocking until it becomes
> determined or failed.
>
> There are four kinds of futures:
>
> - concurrent futures stand for the result of a concurrent computation,
> - lazy futures stand for the result of a computation that is only performed on request,
> - promised futures stand for a value that is promised to be delivered later by explicit means,
> - failed futures represent the result of a computation that terminated with an exception.

Answer (score 5):

## [Software transactional memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory)

> In computer science, software
> transactional memory (STM) is a
> concurrency control mechanism
> analogous to database transactions for
> controlling access to shared memory in
> concurrent computing. It is an
> alternative to lock-based
> synchronization. A transaction in this
> context is a piece of code that
> executes a series of reads and writes
> to shared memory. These reads and
> writes logically occur at a single
> instant in time; intermediate states
> are not visible to other (successful)
> transactions. The idea of providing
> hardware support for transactions
> originated in a 1986 paper and patent
> by Tom Knight[1]. The idea was
> popularized by Maurice Herlihy and J.
> Eliot B. Moss[2]. In 1995 Nir Shavit
> and Dan Touitou extended this idea to
> software-only transactional memory
> (STM)[3]. STM has recently been the
> focus of intense research and support
> for practical implementations is
> growing.

Answer (score 4):

There's also map/reduce.

The idea is to spawn many instances of a sub problem and to combine the answers when they're done. A simple example would be matrix multiplication, which is the sum of several dot products. You spawn a worker thread for each dot product, and when all the threads are finished you sum the result.

This is how GPUs, functional languages such as LISP/Scheme/APL, and some frameworks (Google's Map/Reduce) handle concurrency.

Comment: Thanks for the simple matrix multiplication example

Answer (score 2):

## [Coroutines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine)

> In computer science, coroutines are
> program components that generalize
> subroutines to allow multiple entry
> points for suspending and resuming
> execution at certain locations.
> Coroutines are well-suited for
> implementing more familiar program
> components such as cooperative tasks,
> iterators, infinite lists and pipes.

Answer (score 1):

There's also non-blocking concurrency such as compare-and-swap and load-link/store-conditional instructions. For example, compare-and-swap (cas) could be defined as so:

bool cas( int new_value, int current_value, int * location );

This operation will then attempt to set the value at location to the value passed in new_value, but only if the value in location is the same as current_value. This only requires one instruction and is usually how blocking concurrency (mutexes/semaphores/etc.) are implemented.

Comment: compare-and-swap and load-link/store-conditional instructions are hardware support for building concurrent model. They are considered building blocks of concurrency model, not a model per se.

Answer (score 1):

## [IPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) (including [MPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface) and [RMI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html))

Hi,
in the wiki pages you can find that MPI (message passing interface) is a methods of a general IPC technique: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication
Another interesting approach is a Remote procedure call. For example Java's RMI enables you
to focus only on your application domain and communication patterns. It's an "application level" concurrency.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html

There a various design patterns/tools available to aid in shared memory model prallelization. Apart from the mentioned futures one can also take advantage of:
1. Thread pool pattern - focuses on task distribution between fixed number of threads: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern
2. Scheduler pattern - controls the threads execution according to a chosen scheduling policy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduler_pattern
3. Reactor pattern - to embed a single threaded application in a parallel environment http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern
4. OpenMP (allows to parallelize part of code by means of preprocessor pragmas)

Regards,
Marcin

Answer (score 1):

Parallel Random Access Machine (PRAM) is useful for complexity/tractability isues (please refer to a [nice book](http://www.cs.washington.edu/homes/ruzzo/papers/limits.pdf) for details).

About models you will also find something [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/parallel_comp/#Models) (by Blaise Barney)

Answer (score 1):

How about [tuple space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple_space)?

> A tuple space is an implementation of the associative memory paradigm
>   for parallel/distributed computing. It provides a repository of tuples
>   that can be accessed concurrently. As an illustrative example,
>   consider that there are a group of processors that produce pieces of
>   data and a group of processors that use the data. Producers post their
>   data as tuples in the space, and the consumers then retrieve data from
>   the space that match a certain pattern. This is also known as the
>   blackboard metaphor. Tuple space may be thought as a form of
>   distributed shared memory.

Answer (score 1):

**LMAX's disruptor pattern** keeps data in place and assures only one thread (consumer or producer) is owner of a data item (=queue slot) at a time.